# Tokbox Screen Sharing On/Off Toggle in iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, opentok, tokbox, screensharing

I want to provide screen sharing **On/Off** Feature in iOS Using **Tokbox**.

I am able to switch to device screen share but after sharing the screen I am not able to switch back to the device Camara.

I have tried with the following code.

```
-(void)toogleScreen{
    if (isSharingEnable == YES) {
        isSharingEnable = NO;
        NSLog(@"%@",_publisher.description);

        _publisher.videoCapture = nil;
        [_publisher setVideoType:OTPublisherKitVideoTypeCamera];
       _publisher.audioFallbackEnabled = YES;
    } else {
        isSharingEnable = YES;
          [_publisher setVideoType:OTPublisherKitVideoTypeScreen];
        _publisher.audioFallbackEnabled = NO;

         TBScreenCapture* videoCapture =
        [[TBScreenCapture alloc] initWithView:self.view];
        [_publisher setVideoCapture:videoCapture];
    }
}
```

Comment: They have an accelerator pack to do it. https://github.com/opentok/screensharing-annotation-acc-pack

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might not be setting any video capturer when turning off screencapture. This line:

```
        _publisher.videoCapture = nil;
```

Is needlessly destructive. Try keeping a internal references to the camera and screen capturers, and initialize them outside of the toggleScreen function:

```
@implementation MyPublisher {
  id <OTVideoCapture> _cameraCapture;
  id <OTVideoCapture> _screenCapture;
}
```

Then, change your toggle method to something like:

```
-(void)toogleScreen{
    if (isSharingEnable == YES) {
        isSharingEnable = NO;
        [_publisher setVideoCapture:_cameraCapture];
        [_publisher setVideoType:OTPublisherKitVideoTypeCamera];
       _publisher.audioFallbackEnabled = YES;
    } else {
        isSharingEnable = YES;
        [_publisher setVideoCapture:_screenCapture];
        [_publisher setVideoType:OTPublisherKitVideoTypeScreen];
        _publisher.audioFallbackEnabled = NO;    
    }
}
```